# I need to do a delete and update based on status

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, validation, django-models

I need to do a delete and update based on status.

Here are models:

```
class Purchases(TimeStampedModel):
    APROVADO = "AP"
    EM_VALIDACAO = "VA"
    STATUS_CHOICHES = (
        (APROVADO, "Aprovado"),
        (EM_VALIDACAO, "Em validação"),
    )
    values = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
    cpf = BRCPFField("CPF")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICHES, default=EM_VALIDACAO)
```

I'm trying to do like this in my viewset:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if self.action in ("update", "parcial_update", "delete"):
            qs.filter(Purchases.status=="VA")
        return qs
```

However he is still letting edit the orders with the approved status. Can only be deleted or edited purchase with status "In validation"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[**`qs.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) does *not* filter the queryset `qs`. It construct a *new* queryset that is the filtered variant of `qs`.

You thus should *return* the filtered queryset, or assign the result to `qs`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    if self.action in ('update', 'parcial_update', 'delete'):
        return qs.filter(Purchases.status=='VA')
    return qs
```

Comment: I made the change, however I can still change it with the other status